# Conditionally Change Color Apex/Visualforce Lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

Would someone be able to help me with two questions;

I am writing a simple VisualForce page to display some key record information on lightning page for our sales manager to know their email address health.  Currently I have the following code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact"> <p style="font-size:20px">This is where we will place information on the email health status</p> <p style="font-size:14px"> Record Source: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Record_Source2__c}"/> <br/> Email Opt Out: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail}"/> <br/> Email Opt In:<br/> Email Error: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Email_Error__c}"/> <br/> Last Modified: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.LastCURequestDate}"/> </p> </apex:page>
```

Questions
1)  If I want to display the last modified date, how would I pull this data?

2. How can I make the text for Email Opt Out: display in RED if the customer has opt-out "True".

​​​​​​​Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Questions 1)  If I want to display the last modified date, how would I pull this data?

Just add this line: `<br/>Last Modified Date: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.LastModifiedDate}"/>`

> How can I make the text for Email Opt Out: display in RED if the customer has opt-out "True".

Here's a [list of functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) you could use in a Visualforce expression.
The one you're looking for is: `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`.
You could use it to add a style (i.e. `color: red;`) to a `span` element.

The visualforce page should look like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <p style="font-size:20px">This is where we will place information on the email health status</p>
    <p style="font-size:14px">Record Source: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Record_Source2__c}"/>
        <br/><span style="{!IF(Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail, 'color: red;', 'color: black;')}">Email Opt Out</span>: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail}"/>
        <br/>Email Opt In:
        <br/>Email Error: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Email_Error__c}"/>
        <br/>Last Modified: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.LastCURequestDate}"/>
        <br/>Last Modified Date: <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.LastModifiedDate}"/>
    </p>
</apex:page>
```